# Multiple checkboxes to variable logic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I am looking to create a simple page using HTML and (probably) PHP or JQuery. The page should allow for multiple checkbox selection, and give a variable a value based on which boxes are checked. This can be on submit or can render live on the page.

i.e.

Checkbox 1 

Checkbox 2

Checkbox 3

If checkbox 1 is checked, variable = X

If checkbox 1 & 2 are checked, variable = Y

If no checkboxes are checked, variable = Z

What is the best way to approach doing this?

Comment: if you're only limited to 3 check boxes to determine a variable's value,a basic if-else-if function would be the easiest and most straight forward approach.

Comment: The question is very broad, it looks like you did not do any research into this. If you did, please share your findings in your question. You do not provide any code whatsoever. The solution depends partly on personal preferences. That said I think it is normal to process the results just before submitting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be using Javascript (because it'd be done live) but if you are doing this with PHP. The form would be something like

```
<form action='phplogic.php' method='post>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="Yes" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="Yes" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="Yes" />
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

phplogic would would look like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST[checkbox1']) && (isset($_POST['checkbox2']))  {
$variable = 'Y';
} else (isset($_POST[checkbox1'])) {
$variable = 'X';
} else {
$variable = 'Z';
}
```

Although this doesn't address if checkbox 2 alone is checked but you get the point. You can do something very similar with javascript. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_value.asp